# Uso de PIL y Pillow en Python versión: (Pillow 9.2.0) (Python 3.10.5)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pillow

Estoy aprendiendo de Python apenas, y estoy aprendiendo del uso de Pillow. Al código lo estoy desarrollando tanto en Ubuntu 22.0 LTS como en Windows 10; en Ubuntu no he tenido problemas, pero en Windows al momento de tratar de imprimir una imagen, no me lo permite, me dice lo siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
   File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\Python\21-Tkinter\03-imagenes.py", line 2, in <module>
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

Ya estuve indagando en la documentación pero no menciona nada: busqué en videos en YouTube, en Google y tampoco. Mi código es el siguiente

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

ventana = Tk()
ventana.geometry("400x400")

Label(ventana, text="LOREM").pack(anchor=W)

imagen = Image.open('./21-Tkinter/imagenes/ciborgredimencionado.png')
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagen)
Label(ventana, image=render).pack()
ventana.mainloop()
```

En Ubuntu ese código me funciona bien, pero cuando traté de hacerlo en Windows no me lo permitió. Ya intenté reinstalar Python, desinstalé e instalé VSCode así como todas sus extensiones, desinstalé toda la paquetería de Python, también he desinstalado todo de 'pip'. Lo que tenía instalado con pip es

```
certifi            2022.6.15
charset-normalizer 2.1.0
idna               3.3
Pillow             9.2.0
pip                22.2
requests           2.28.1
setuptools         63.2.0
urllib3            1.26.10
```

También he reconfigurado el path y nada, en el curso el que lo enseña usa Pillow v7.1.1 y la disponible ahora es la 9.2.0.

Para la instalación de Pillow seguí [las instrucciones de este enlace](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) y para la revisión de las versiones disponibles seguí [este otro enlace](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/). El curso que estoy tomando es este: [Master en Python: Aprender Python 3, Django, Flask y Tkinter](https://www.udemy.com/share/102Ows/) de Victor Robles.

Comment: Cuando suceden estos problemas de que se instala una librería, el nombre del modulo está bien escrito y falla la importación, pregunto "¿Tenes más de una versión de Python instalada?". Por que? Por que quizá instalaste el modulo en una versión y ejecutas el script en otra versión que no tiene pillow instalado.

Comment: No, no tengo mas versiones de Python, solo tengo la versión 3.10.5 instalada, junto con npm, la versión de npm que tengo es la 8.11.0, no se si influya en algo

Comment: Estas trabajando en un entorno virtual? si es así asegúrate de tenerlo activado y de que el módulo esté instalado en ese entorno.

Comment: No, no es un entorno virtual, lo instale directamente a Windows, descargue Python de la pagina oficial, he hice el proceso de instalación, y lo mismo, para instalar la librería de Pillow solo ejecute:
(python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip) y 
(python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow)
Y cuando quise usar la librería no me lo permitió